# unable to navigate from custom cell to other view in ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios

I have one class name is `searchresultviewcontroller` another `customcell` class is `searchresultcell` in that class i have one `UIButton` when clicked on that button at that time will navigate to other class. a atteched customcell `xib` image [image]

// for .h file

```
@class SearchResultViewController;
@interface searchresultcellCell : UITableViewCell{


IBOutlet UIButton *btnReadMore;
SearchResultViewController *parent;
```

}

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)SearchResultViewController *parent;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *btnReadMore;
-(IBAction)btnMore:(id)sender;

// .m file
-(void)btnMore:(id)sender{
         NSLog(@"Sucess");
AboutViewController *objAbout = [[AboutViewController       alloc]initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController" bundle:Nil ];
[parent.navigationController pushViewController:objAbout animated:YES];

 }
```

Comment: @BhavikKama,Suryakant Sharma  i edited my question

Comment: Did you set the parent property on the cell? Try to log its value

Comment: in button click it was print log i.e Sucess but don't open AboutViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will not solve by parentiew controller option

there is two option you can use

1. You can add Notification in the view controller class and call that
   notification from the method of custom cell class
2. Use Protocols-delegate